# Sheave of sets, what does $\{f_i \} \mapsto \{f_i \mid_{U_i \cap U_j}\}$ mean?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, continuity, category-theory, sheaf-theory

> ... for an open covering $U = \bigcup U_i$, an $I$-indexed family of functions $f_i : U_i \to \Bbb{R}, \ i \in I$, is an element of the product set $\prod_i CU_i$, **while the assignments $\{f_i\} \mapsto \{f_i \mid_{U_i \cap U_j}\}$ and $\{f_i\} \mapsto \{ f_j \mid_{U_i \cap U_j}\}$define two maps $p$ and $q$** of $I$-indexed sets to $(I\times I)$-index sets, as in the diagram

$$
e: C U \dashrightarrow \prod\limits_i C U_i \xrightarrow{p, q} \prod\limits_{i,j} C(U_i \cap U_j)
$$

(from "Sheaves in Geometry & Logic" pg. 65)

I'm having trouble with the bolded part, in particular: do they mean $i \neq j$ or something?  I'm not seeing why / how these $p, q$ definitions work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that these become clearer when rewritten with a different restriction symbol and with explicit indexing. We're sending the $I$-indexed set $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ to the $I^2$-indexed set $(f_i\upharpoonright U_i\cap U_j)_{i,j\in I}$, respectively the $I^2$-indexed set $(f_j\upharpoonright U_i\cap U_j)_{i,j\in I}$.

(In particular, I think using "$\vert$" for restriction in the context of set builder notation is unnecessarily confusing. But oh well.)

Comment: But aren't the two families then one and the same by commutativity of $\cap$?

Comment: @RollupandsmokeAdjoint Not *as indexed families*. E.g. taking $i=2, j=3$ we get that the $(i,j)$th element of the first is $f_2\upharpoonright U_2\cap U_3$ but the $(i,j)$th element of the second is $f_3\upharpoonright U_2\cap U_3$. Obviously there's a translation between them - the $(i,j)$th element of the first is the $(j,i)$th element of the second - but they are literally different objects.

Comment: I still don't get how those two indexed families are the different

Comment: @RollupandsmokeAdjoint I mean, they are literally different objects. In the same way that the sequence $(1,2,3)$ is different from the sequence $(3,2,1)$ - it's not just what appears on the sequence, but *where* as well. This is why the term "indexed set," as opposed to simply "set," is crucial: it's changing the *type* of object under consideration, and so data we might think of as unimportant is actually meaningful (even if it feels silly).

Comment: Ah, i see, they're only different because they are $(i,j)$-indexed.